# How to dynamically add parameter values to JdbcTemplate query?

Tags: java, file-io, spring-jdbc

I need to query the DB but the parameter values from that query need to come from a file, here is the code...

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/DBMigrations/empIDs.txt"));
String line = null;
String query = "select name, address from Employee where id in (";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // the value of line needs to be plugged into query inside the in clause
    }
```

I am using Spring's SimpleJdbcTemplate.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you going to create single sql corresponding to single row in file ?? Mean you will have multiple query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply have one method which generates a token of concatenated ids from file.

```
String query = "select name, address from Employee where id in ("+geneateEmployeeIds()+")";

private String geneateEmployeeIds(){

 // read your file here and convert it to string<br>
 // do id concatenation here
  return ids;
}
```

You can have an idea of how you can get the string content of file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)